# White corner in freshly baked whole wheat bread

Tags: bread

I baked a whole wheat bread last night and while cutting into slices I noticed that there are white colour powdery line on few of the slices. This is the second time this is happening. Attached is a picture - the right side of the slice has a white line - is this normal? What could be the reason for this? Would it be one side being heated a bit more (back side of my otg gets heated up a bit more and this white corner is from that end)

I followed KAF whole wheat bread recipe without seeds and nuts.[image]

Comment: Do you see the difference in pore structure? You aren't kneading the dough the right way, or not long enough.

Comment: Manual or machine kneaded? Is there any white flour in there as well? Or used to dust work surfaces?

Comment: Yes i agree with the not right way of kneading. But i was told I overkneaded it by another baker. She said that's why the density difference. About the flour, for this batch i did not use any  flour to dust the surface to rule out that possibility (since this was the second time i faced the issue). I used a stand mixer to mix it.

Answer (score 3):

"white colour powdery lines" is flour. It means that your dough is not mixed enough.
Also either your oven is not heated enough (and/or it heat from one side) or when the dough is resting one side of it become more cold that stop dough from working and that's why you have difference in density.

Comment: Yeah i feel it gets heated up more on one side. The white portion is from that end of the oven. What can we do about uneven heating in ovens to avoid such issues? Any suggestions? About the density i was told i overkneaded it.

Comment: Do some test. Make some round flatbread and observe how they bake on different tiers. if that a case try placing some reflecting shield (form small baking tray or even tin foil) that would force hot air to move to opposite part of the oven. And in the end turn the bread mid bake.